# Loop through api call in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have an api that returns 50 users.

Is there a way of looping through the api call

```
expand=users%5B1%3A50%5D
```

The **1** after **B** is the starting number and it will pull until **50** which is the number after **A**

I have a script that will store the responses to a text file but how can I loop through this adding increments of 50?

For example. having a variable in place of the numbers

```
expand=users%5B$num1%3A$num2%5D
```

Answer (score 1):

```
expand=users%5B{1..50}%3A50%5D
```

The `{1..5}` will expand as `1 2 3 4 5`

for example

```
$ echo abc{1..5}def 
abc1def abc2def abc3def abc4def abc5def
```

now all you need is to loop over the `expand`

```
for api in $expand
do
#do something
done
```